# Laravel store DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have a little problem.. When I´m trying to store in a database in laravel it´s show me an error like this

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usuario' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `tipificaciones` (`usuario`, `origen`, `estado`, `nombreCliente`, `caso`, `venta`, `palabraClave`, `updated_at`, `fecha`) values (Supervisor, Leads, 1, ssd, 129308jk, 1, sdañldaskñasd, 2020-06-05 10:58:58, 2020-06-05 10:58:58))"
```

When i see my DB this Column exist, I verify the connection to DB was successfull becouse in another view I return info for another table.

This is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\modelo;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TipificacionesModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tipificaciones';
    protected $fillable = ['id','usuario', 'origen', 'estado', 'nombreCliente', 'caso', 'venta', 'palabraClave'];
    const CREATED_AT = 'fecha';
}
```

And my Controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        TipificacionesModel::create([
            'usuario'=>$request['usuario'],
            'origen'=>$request['origen'],
            'estado'=>$request['estado'],
            'nombreCliente'=>$request['nombreCliente'],
            'caso'=>$request['caso'],
            'venta'=>$request['venta'],
            'palabraClave'=>$request['palabraClave'],
        ]);

        return("true");
    }
```

My database

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TueZQ.png)

How I can fix this

Thanks for colaboration!

Comment: Show your create table for `tipificaciones`

Comment: In the post is the image

Comment: check your migrations matching the usuario column with your model

Comment: If i dont use migrations can be my error?